# Forward Windows 2012 event logs from workgroup host to domain host

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-event-log, pci-dss

Is this possible? I've gone through the following but no events are forwarded.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc748890(v=ws.11)

I have a DMZ server that I want to forward logs from to another server in my domain.

This is to satisfy PCI logging requirements so if there's a better way, please let me know.

Comment: Have you successfully setup event forwarding from other servers that are not in the DMZ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible when the Event Forwarding client and Event Collector server have certificates installed for authentication. Check out the 'Setting up a source initiated subscription where the event sources are not in the same domain as the event collector computer' section of [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb870973(v=vs.85).aspx).